# Symfony 6.1 Doctrine gives error 'Could not resolve type of column "id" of class "App\Entity\Officecurrencymax"'

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am getting the error `Could not resolve type of column "id" of class "App\Entity\Officecurrencymax"` from my installation. Have checked similar questions but I can't seem to get the Doctrine annotations right.

I have 2 entities with a ManyToOne relationship, Office and OfficeCurrencyMax. One Office can have many OfficeCurrencyMax's.

```
/**
 * Office
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Office")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\OfficeRepository")
 */
class Office
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Officecurrencymax", inversedBy="offices")
     */
    private $officeCurrencyMaxes;

    // ...

    public function getOfficeCurrencyMaxes(): ?Officecurrencymax
    {
        return $this->officeCurrencyMaxes;
    }

    public function setOfficeCurrencyMaxes(?Officecurrencymax $officeCurrencyMaxes): self
    {
        $this->officeCurrencyMaxes = $officeCurrencyMaxes;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Then there is the Officecurrencymax entity:

```
/**
 * Officecurrencymax
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="OfficeCurrencyMax", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_6F39111B73FD6E34", columns={"Office"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\OfficeCurrencyMaxRepository")
 */
class Officecurrencymax
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Office
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Office", inversedBy="offices")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Office", referencedColumnName="OfficeId")
     * })
     */
    private $office;

    // ...

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    // ...
}
```

I had to cut down the code a lot since StackOverflow wouldn't let me post since `it looks like your post is mainly code, please add some more details`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you want to have **1-**`Office` have **Many-**`Officecurrencymax`

So `Office` should have a `OneToMany` property and `Officecurrencymax` a `ManyToOne`.

There are a few errors, for example your Office entity says that the property is inversed by:  `inversedBy="offices"` whereas `$offices` does not exist in the `Officecurrencymax` entity.

Your [OneToMany](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.13/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) in `Office` should look like:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Officecurrencymax, mappedBy="office")
 */
private $officeCurrencyMaxes;
```

And in Officecurrencymax we have the opposite side of the relation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Office, inversedBy="officeCurrencyMaxes")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Office", referencedColumnName="OfficeId")
 */
private $office;
```

Do not forget to update the database schema.

Comment: I have set this up as you suggest, however when I retrieve $officeCurrencyMaxes from the Office entity, I get a Collection of Offices, not of OfficeCurrencyMaxes...

Comment: That's what happens if I dump the returned collection, if I don't dump it and try to use the collection in a foreach loop (eg `$currencyMaxes = $this->loggedUser->getOffice()->getOfficecurrencymaxes(); foreach ($currencyMaxes as $cm)`, I get the error `Undefined array key "id"`

Comment: @craigh was also right about the issue with your Id property, you should be able to redefine it with the code I added in ym answer. Unless overriding default behavior, it's better to have simple annotations (for example: don't name your table column yourself).

Comment: I'm working with an existing database. But anyway, it has nothing to do with the Id column, the error message is a red-herring. I fixed it finally by adding the join column to the ManyToOne side `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="Office", referencedColumnName="OfficeId")`. If you want to add this to your answer, I'll accept it as the solution. Add a link to the docs too: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.13/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: I edited my answer, indeed as mentionned you have overidden default naming behavior so you need to explicitly configure your relation. I would advise (if you have no specific naming convention for your database) to keep the default behavior to prevent this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

based on [these docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.13/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional) I would assume the default column name for your mapping should be `id` (note the case). You have **capitalized** your column name for some reason

`@ORM\Column(name="Id" ...`

I would suggest simply changing that to

`@ORM\Column(name="id" ...`

Comment: The column name in the database is Id, not id. In those docs, the example is using a column name of id. But the column name needs to be that used in your specific database, not that in an example in the documentation